# Multiple lineplot with Errobar for data coming from two tables

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I have two data sheets, one with the points I want to plot (each point in the first data set is an average of different measurements), and the second data containing the standard deviations for each point.

Below I attached an R script to create lineplot from the first data which works fine. With the code i can create a plot like the following

[image]

Now I want to use the second table (standard deviations) to create a plot similar the previous, but now also showing a errorbar, i.e., that graphically displays the standard deviation of each measurements like [this](https://i2.wp.com/svbtleusercontent.com/ihtbtwwsa9ww7w.png?ssl=1).

```
  library(ggplot2)

##loads a dataframe and returns a ggplot object that can be externally modified and plotted
makeMultipleLinePlot <- function(data){

  require(reshape2)
  data$id <-rownames(data)
  melted <- melt(data)
  colnames(melted)<-c("Measurement","Month","Percentage")
  g<-ggplot(data=melted,
            aes(x=Month, y=Percentage, color=Measurement,group=Measurement)) +
    geom_line(size=1,alpha=0.8) + geom_point(size=4,aes(shape=Measurement))
  return(g)
}  


##load a table from google sheets. assumes the sheet has a single table
loadTableFromGoogleSheet <- function(url, sheet) {
  require(gsheet)
  a <- gsheet2text(url,sheetid=sheet, format='csv')
  data <- read.csv(text=a, stringsAsFactors=FALSE,header = TRUE,row.names = 1)
  return(data)
}


#URL of the google spreadsheet
url <- "docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10clnt9isJp_8Sr7A8ejhKEZXCQ279wGP4sdygsit1LQ"

gid.humidity    <- 2080295295  #gid of the google sheet containing humidity data
data.humidity<-loadTableFromGoogleSheet(url,gid.humidity)

gid.humidity_sd <- 1568896731 #gid of the google sheet containing standard deviations for each measurement in the humidity data
data.humidity_sd<-loadTableFromGoogleSheet(url,gid.humidity_sd)

ggsave(filename="lineplot/humidity.pdf", plot=makeMultipleLinePlot(data.humidity))  
#ggsave(filename="lineplot/humidity.pdf", plot=makeMultipleErrorPlot(data.humidity,data.humidity_sd))
```

Comment: see http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_errorbar.html you can add the error bars to your points using `geom_errorbar(data=data2, aes(x, sd))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tidy the two `data.frame`, join them and `plot` the result, using `geom_errorbar`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.humidity %>% 
  mutate(measure = row.names(.)) %>% 
  gather(month, value, -measure) 


df_sd <- data.humidity_sd %>% 
  mutate(measure = substr(row.names(.), 1, 2)) %>% 
  gather(month, sd, -measure)

dfF <- full_join(df, df_sd)
#> Joining, by = c("measure", "month")


ggplot(dfF, aes(month, value, group = measure, color = measure))+
  geom_line(size=1,alpha=0.8) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = measure)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = value - sd, ymax = value + sd), width = .3)
```

[image]

Comment: This solves the problem in a very elegant way, thank you very much!